# proper arrangement of npm workspaces and peer dependencies

Tags: npm, vite, peer-dependencies, npm-workspaces

I built a vue3 component library, which is the root of my folder

```
src/...
package.json
```

I added a demo app to the repository that just showcases components and aids in development of components.

```
src/...
package.json
demo/...
demo/package.json
```

I currently have the root package.json setup with

```
"workspaces": ["./demo" ]
```

I also made sure that any dependencies in the root that also are required in demo are under "peerDependencies".

In practice this is very flaky, I keep getting errors like

> Vite Error, /node_modules/.vite/deps/shared-dependency.js?v=7ec6316e optimized info should be defined (x12)